# operator++() nothrow does not compile

Tags: c++, nothrow

Why can't I make operator++() nothrow?

This could be one of the few advantages of using the postfix ++ operator (over the prefix ++ operator).

For example, this code does not compile

```
class Number
{
public:
    Number& operator++ ()     // ++ prefix
    {
        ++m_c;
        return *this;
    }

    Number operator++ (int) nothrow  // postfix ++
    {
        Number result(*this);   // make a copy for result
        ++(*this);              // Now use the prefix version to do the work
        return result;          // return the copy (the old) value.
    }

    int m_c;
};
```

On a side note it the postfix operator could also be made thread-safe.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not declaring the prefix operator `nothrow`? It would help to know what the compiler is complaining about, but I figure it could be a simple as a `nothrow` postfix operator complaining when you use a non-`nothrow` prefix operator to implement it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: That's it exactly.  `nothrow` functions can't call potentially throwing functions.

Comment: In VC 2015 I get: error C3646: 'nothrow': unknown override specifier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`nothrow`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/nothrow/) is a constant used to pass to operator new to indicate that new should not throw an exception on error.

I think what you want is [noexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept).

Comment: A bit strange why we need two keywords in C++ they seem similar to me.

Comment: @Damian `nothrow` is not a keyword in C++, it's a constant of type `std::nothrow_t`.

Comment: technically nothrow is not a keyword. It's a constant in the std namespace. But I agree, it is confusing (even the commenters on your question were confused).

Comment: @Damian that's because nothrow was there even before the idea of noexcept. You can't change the meaning of an existing entity because of the havoc it will create. C++ is not python. The committee continues to carry the burden of backward compatibility.